# Transformer Voltage unknown number of turns

Tags: transformer, inductor, inductance, coil

[image: Transformer circuit]

I am trying to find the Voltage across the open end of the secondary side of this transfromer. I have been given V1=50V, R1=20ohms, R2=20ohms, XL1=XL2=40ohms. I have found the primary current so far using ohms law V1/R1+XL1 but I am stuck with what to do next?

Comment: You made the mistake at the beginning. You cannot find the primary current by simply dividing source voltage to (R1+XL1). Remember the total impedance is a complex number!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to know the primary current if, as I suspect, the question is about two inductors that have 100% coupling (i.e. a perfect transformer). When coupling is 100% and both have the same inductance, you can assume that they both have the same number of turns and this makes it a 1:1 device.

So, work out the RMS voltage on L1 and it will be the same on L2 (open circuit output).

> I have found the primary current so far using ohms law V1/R1+XL1

No, you have to use pythagorus when adding resistive and reactive elements: -

[image]

Comment: I got the same impedence. This is what I did. (20+j40)ohms and then I calculated it in polar form and then divided it with Voltage in polar form which gave me current in primary in polar form. Correct me if I'm wrong please but will VL1 be current in primary side times the impedance or would it be the value found using voltage divider rule? And yes the inductors have 100% coupling.

Comment: Either rule will work but VD rule is quicker. Having said that, if you havee the current just multiply by |XL| to get V.

Answer (score 0):

I will not give the full solution here, but I'll show the most important step:

Since the primary circuit consists of a resistor and an inductor, total impedance will be a complex number:
$$
Z = R + j \ X_L
$$

So if you want to find the primary current first to obtain the voltage drop across the primary winding, primary current will be:

$$
I_p = \frac{V_S}{|Z|} = \frac{V_S}{\sqrt {R^2 + X_L^2}}
$$

Take it from here and find the rest by yourself.

Comment: I am really sorry I didn't specify but I calculated the impedance in polar form so I have the same answer as you would get using pythogorus. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the voltage on the secondary side as your question asks, no math is needed. We can see by inspection XL1 = XL2 and R1=R2. From this information we can infer the that windings on the two sides of the transformer are the same (1:1) and the source and load impedances are equal. Therefore the secondary voltage is equal to the primary voltage (V1=V2).